# gevent fd must be non-negative: -1

Tags: docker, uwsgi, gevent, django-wsgi, gevent-socketio

I am using [django-websocket-redis](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) to setup websocket. Also using nginx and docker. I followed what mentioned in the usage, got error when trying to hit the server from client.

Here is my nginx.conf

```
  location /api {
    include             /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param         HTTP_HOST {{ 'DOMAIN_NAME' | env }};
    uwsgi_pass          uwsgi://{{ upstream }};
    uwsgi_read_timeout  600;
}

 location /ws/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    include         /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param     HTTP_HOST {{ 'DOMAIN_NAME' | env }};
    uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/app_ws.sock;
}
```

And here my uwsgi:

```
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir               = $(SRC)/
# Django's wsgi file
module              = config.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
# home                = $(DEPLOY_ROOT)/app/
# process-related settings
# master
master              = true

# set up app load optimizations
workers             = 4         # maximum number of workers
cheaper             = 2         # minimum number of workers at all times
cheaper-initial     = 2         # num. of workers spawned at startup
cheaper-step        = 1         # num. of workers spawned when algo decides more are needed
cheaper-algo        = spare     # (spare2) faster spawning, slower disposing
cheaper-busyness-verbose = true

# align header size with ELB
buffer-size         = 16384

# use network socket
socket              = :xxxx

# clear environment on exit
vacuum              = true

# reload django app on file change (debug only)
if-env              = PYTHON_AUTORELOAD
python-autoreload   = %(_)
end-if              =

pythonpath          = $(SRC)/
base                = $(SRC)/
```

Here is my uwsgi for websocket:

```
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir               = $(SRC)/
# Django's wsgi file
module              = config.wsgi_websocket
# the virtualenv (full path)
# home                = $(DEPLOY_ROOT)/app/

http-websockets = true
gevent          = 1000

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true

# set up app load optimizations
workers         = 4         # maximum number of workers
cheap           = 2         # minimum number of workers at all times
cheaper-initial = 2         # num. of workers spawned at startup
cheaper-step    = 1         # num. of workers spawned when algo decides more are needed
cheaper-algo    = spare     # (spare2) faster spawning, slower disposing

# align header size with ELB
buffer-size     = 16384
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/app_ws.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 667
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true

# reload django app on file change (debug only)
if-env = PYTHON_AUTORELOAD
python-autoreload = %(_)
end-if =


pythonpath          = $(SRC)/
base                = $(SRC)/
```

Here is the error I got.

```
app_1         | *** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x493be0] ***
app_1         | Python auto-reloader enabled
app_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1         |   File "gevent.libev.corecext.pyx", line 490, in gevent.libev.corecext.loop.io (src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:6698)
app_1         |   File "gevent.libev.corecext.pyx", line 490, in gevent.libev.corecext.loop.io (src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:6698)
app_1         |   File "gevent.libev.corecext.pyx", line 850, in gevent.libev.corecext.io.__init__ (src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:11105)
app_1         |   File "gevent.libev.corecext.pyx", line 850, in gevent.libev.corecext.io.__init__ (src/gevent/libev/gevent.corecext.c:11105)
app_1         | ValueError: fd must be non-negative: -1
app_1         | ValueError: fd must be non-negative: -1
```

And with out websocket, my app works fine , meaning I can hit url under /api.

Comment: If this were purely a *configuration* problem, it would be a better fit for ServerFault than StackOverflow. That said, it looks likely to be a code problem (file descriptors legitimately aren't allowed to be negative at the OS level, so anything that's generating or returning one is quite certainly buggy) -- but right now, you don't actually provide any code, only configuration.

Comment: ...so, I'd start by looking at the uwsgi code that's responsible for actually opening the socket and seeing how it behaves in failure cases; if it returns -1, well, there's your problem (and you have a few next steps: identifying and correcting the error that happened, and improving the error handling so it fails early instead of passing an invalid FD number to the rest of the system).